# Do memory addresses on the heap get reused?

Tags: c++, memory

A further explanation of the title question is in order, let me explain my scenario.

I have a list container of pointers to several objects on the heap. Whenever a new object is created a pointer to it is added to the list and whenever an object is deleted its pointer is removed. It is safe to say that all pointers on this list are always valid.

Many of the objects on the list contain pointers to other objects on the same list.

Before I dereference any of those pointers I would like to use a `CheckAgainstList(ptr*)` function to make sure that the one object is pointing to another object on the same list and is therefore not pointing to an object that has since been deleted.

Get your tinfoil hats on now, Is this possible?

1. Object A has a pointer to object B with a memory address of
   `0x00988e50`.
2. Object B is deleted.
3. Object C is created and is placed into the newly freed memory space `0x00988e50`.
4. `CheckAgainstList(ptr*)` returns true when we check the pointer because object C is on the list and is in the same memory address B used to occupy.

Now we have a bug because A thinks it has a pointer to B, but B is gone and C has taken its place so to speak.

Is this potential bug even possible?

Comment: Not just possible - its likely. If you free B and allocate C right after it is likely with many heap implementations that you will get the same buffer right back.

Comment: Came here googling on how often this happens, after seeing memory chunks being obviously reused (for data of same type). So, yes :)

Answer (score 7):

Not only is it possible, it's very likely. A good memory allocator will try to reuse memory as often as possible to reduce fragmentation and bloat.

The problem you're trying to solve might be amenable to a [weak_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr), which can be checked for validity before it's used.

Answer (score 4):

Yes that bug is entirely possible.

Basically what you are doing is pretty dangerous and will lead to bugs pretty quickly.  You may be best off using a reference counted smart ptr of some sort.  C++11 includes std::shared_ptr which means you can use in place of your normal pointer.  This way the memory won't get freed until everything has finished with it and would alleviate issues like you describe.

Your only other option would be to scan through all other objects to see if they reference the deleted 'B' and do something like "null" out their pointers to the, now deleted, pointer.

Answer (score 4):

The memory addresses do get reused - depending on the operating system. Otherwise, if a program does lots of allocations and deallocations, more than there's RAM in the machine, it would not be able to continue.

In the end the answer is more about the operating system and it's memory management scheme than C++ itself. After all, at most primitive what happens when you allocate free-store(dynamic) memory is that the process(via the standard library function) calls a specific OS routine to allocate requested amount of memory and return the address to the allocated memory.

Answer (score 1):

The bug is more likely if you only create a single type of object. But it is always completely possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that can happen. To prevent that, when you delete an object, go through the list and set any pointers to deleted object to point to NULL.